# Using Selenium Webdriver in C#, how do I select a text box to write in, then write in it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, webdriver

Have a script to go to the website. Now I want to login and proceed to next screen.  Can't find code on how to go to 'username:' text box, then 'password:' text box.

Comment: selenium uses the alot of different ways to pick up elements, so you would need to find out the ID,name,css, etc. of the username textbox and the password textbox. then do a `driver.click();` I would suggest name or id for this instance

Comment: This is not a good question, please read [this](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) to help you write better questions. Finding an element is one of the most basic actions of Selenium and can easily be found in the [documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#selenium-webdriver-api-commands-and-operations). There are a range of code samples on the link I've given that should help a lot, and if it doesn't help then you should post your broken code and ask why it doesn't work. Read the page, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You will need to give us some HTML of the page, but given a password textbox like this:

```
<input type="password" id="passwordTextBox">
```

I'd find it using Selenium's WebDriver like so:

```
IWebDriver firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
IWebElement passwordTextBox = firefoxDriver.FindElement(By.Id("passwordTextBox"));
```

I would then 'write' into it like so:

```
passwordTextBox.Clear();
passwordTextBox.SendKeys("password");
```

I would take a look at the Selenium Web Driver documentation, and ask any questions after you've read through it all:

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html

Answer (score 0):

```
//Textbox  id is "username"
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();    
string url = "https://www.google.com";
IWebElement textBox;
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
textBox = driver.FindElement(By.Name("username"));
textBox.SendKeys("Test text");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.FindElement(selectBy(controlToFind, search)).Click();
```

Just need to use this code.

- `driver` = your selenium web driver
- `SelectBy(controlToFind)` = this is your control, xpath code, CSS selector or class.
- `.Click()` = Represents the action to do, you can use `.click()` , `.SendKeys()` , `wait()` ...

Answer (score -2):

To Type the value in User Name and Password Text Box. Try below

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("\\UserName Text Box ID\\").SendKeys("UserName Text");

driver.FindElement(By.Id("\\Password Text box ID\\").SendKeys("Password Text");
```