# How to get and set text editor value in selenium

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, editor

I have text Editor on a web page, i need to fill its value using selenium scripting in c#. I know how to do it for textbox. i have checked the process from [Set value in textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557196/using-selenium-webdriver-in-c-how-do-i-select-a-text-box-to-write-in-then-wri) but when i have tried the same process for text editor, it is not working, i want to get and set the value of editor. please help me how can i do this.

code for getting text of textbox is :

```
IWebDriver firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
IWebElement passwordTextBox = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("passwordTextBox"));
passwordTextBox.Clear();
passwordTextBox.SendKeys("password");
```

I have tried the below code to set value of editor

```
IWebElement detailFrame = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#cke_1_contents .cke_wysiwyg_frame"));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(detailFrame);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
var body = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")); // then you find the body
Thread.Sleep(1000);
body.SendKeys("<span>hiiiiiiii<span>");
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: Please correct your `body` which you declared as variable. It should be of `IWebElement` type. Are you sure your texteditor is located by `body` tag. Please post html here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the following code to do this:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementsByClassName('cke_wysiwyg_frame')[0].contentDocument.getElementsByClassName('cke_editable_themed')[0].innerHTML='dfjkbgdk';");
```

that's work for me.....

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you are trying send keys to CKEditor.

Please read through this article: [Test WYSIWYG editors using Selenium WebDriver](http://yizeng.me/2014/01/31/test-wysiwyg-editors-using-selenium-webdriver/)

- Send keys directly

This approach is the one you have tried and didn't work. It's known to have issues with Firefox. Your code should work for PhantomJS or Chrome. Note that `<span>hiiiiiiii<span>` will result in actual text in the editor, not a span element.

- Set innerHTML

```c#
IWebElement detailFrame = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#cke_1_contents .cke_wysiwyg_frame"));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(detailFrame);

var body = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")); // then you find the body

var executor = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = '<span>hiiiiiiii<span>'", body);
```

- Use CKEditor's native API

```c#
var executor = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
executor.ExecuteScript("CKEDITOR.instances.ckeditor.setData('<span>hiiiiiiii<span>");
```

Comment: @raman: Which one you did? Describe what happens. If there are exceptions, post stractrace. Also need to state your Selenium version, browser and browser version. If your own answer works, then the second one here should also work, unless you have done something wrong.

Answer (score 7):

```
IWebDriver firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
IWebElement passwordTextBox = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("passwordTextBox"));
passwordTextBox.Clear();
passwordTextBox.SendKeys("password");
```

In above code change 2nd line to

```
IWebElement passwordTextBox = firefoxDriver.FindElement(By.Id("passwordTextBox"));
```

Also check id of element you are searching `By.Id("passwordTextBox")` is correct other wise use xpath/css