# How can i get text price data found in a class with C# using Selenium?

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium

Im a new coder at web and im trying to do a price comparing website. Im trying to get price data from another website to mine. I've got some problems getting text price data. How can i get text under class and write in textbox? Here is my current code:

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            string str ="";
            driver.Url = "https://www.akakce.com/arama/?q=" + TextBox2.Text;
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            str = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='pt_v8']")).GetAttribute("class");
            TextBox1.Text = ("price = " + str);
        }
```

And this is source code at website:

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEMCq.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Selenium Webdriver in C#, how do I select a text box to write in, then write in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557196/using-selenium-webdriver-in-c-how-do-i-select-a-text-box-to-write-in-then-wri)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change this line

```
str = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='pt_v8']")).GetAttribute("class");
```

to this

```
str = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='pt_v8']")).Text;
```

---

Update:

use `GetAttribute("textContent")`

```
String str = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='pb_v8']//span[@class='pt_v8']")).GetAttribute("textContent");
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

[image]

Comment: Not worked. Im tryin to get text under pt_v8 class. You can see it from "picture". My goal is getting price of product. How can i go there?

Comment: That should give you the price value. Are you getting any error or nothing?

Comment: Nothing. In my textbox1 write just "price = " nothing from str. When i look at source website, price name looking just "#text". Should i use that? https://prnt.sc/PPBDaUe9xJJm

Comment: @MehmetTaşkın : can you share me the complete search url?

Comment: https://www.akakce.com/arama/?q= and example https://www.akakce.com/arama/?q=iphone14 its a compare website. Im trying to get data from there.

Comment: @MehmetTaşkın : check my updated answer. I have tested, its working now.

Comment: oh its working. thank you so much. can you guide me to how can i add another prices and list them with order?

Comment: ive got a issue with getting right price. im searching "iphone 14 128gb" and price still same with "iphone14" search and its not updating.

Comment: @MehmetTaşkın : you need to use find_elements() and iterate the list. I appreciate if you post and seprate question with expected output.

Comment: @MehmetTaşkın : please check manually , it is the same price.

Comment: if i search iphone 13 or 12 its showing first price but iphone 14 always showing 42839 TL but in search site first product 42399 TL

Comment: @MehmetTaşkın : when you use automation code it is random the picking the iphone. But manually it is different. put some delay after page load, i can see it is different value. thats why you are getting different value.please check

Comment: okey thank you, i changed my timespan second 5 to 10 and its worked. for my another questions ive opened another question. thank you so much.